# Using celery, send async_apply to specific vhost?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a use case where I'd like to be able to have many clients connect to RabbitMQ but they cannot see each other's messages. I believe using vhosts is the best way to keep privacy between the workers?

I thought I'd be able to pass a `virtual_host` argument to `apply_async` but that's not going to work, I believe I have to make a custom connection like so:

```
from kombu import Connection

my_connection = Connection(virtual_host='new_virtual_host')

task.apply_async(connection=my_connection)
```

However, I bet there's a built in way to do that inside Celery using the settings I already have configured and going through the proper channels in case I switch backends. What is that internal "get connection" function?

This is using **Celery 3.1**

EDIT:

Current attempt, not working in that it seems to just return a regular connection *not* using the specified virtual host...

```
from celery.app import app_or_default
app = app_or_default()
with app.broker_connection(virtual_host='other') as new_connection:
    task.apply_async((data,), connection=new_connection)
```

If I check `new_connection` the `virtual_host` kwarg has been ignored.. hmm...

Answer (score 2):

A ha! So, it turns out Celery accepts the `broker_url` then ignores `virtual_host` since `broker_url` is set. It appears to work fine doing it this way, manually setting the property we want:

```
from celery.app import app_or_default

app = app_or_default()

with app.connection() as new_connection:

    # setting here instead of kwargs above
    new_connection.virtual_host = 'other' 

    task.apply_async((data,), connection=new_connection)
```

Doing it this way when I change any regular `CELERY` or `BROKER` settings, it will apply to these new connections as well -- yay!